# Is it possible to pipe kaniko output from within a docker container to docker load?

Tags: bash, docker

I have a build bash script that uses kaniko to build my docker image.

It looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p images

docker container run \
    --rm \
    -v $PWD:/app \
    --entrypoint="" \
    --privileged \
    gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug \
    /kaniko/executor \
        --context /app \
        --dockerfile /app/Dockerfile \
        --destination=image:latest \
        --tarPath=/app/images/out.tar \
        --no-push

docker load < images/out.tar

rm -rf images
```

This works, but unnecessarily creates a temporary file.
It seems like it would be cleaner just to pipe the output of `executor`, running within the docker container, to `docker load`, which runs outside the docker container.

I tried doing something like:

```sh
...
    /kaniko/executor \
        ...
        --tarPath=/dev/stdout \
        -a stdout \
        ...
        --no-push | docker load
...
```

and it seems to almost work, but the problem is that `executor` generates other messages on stdout that get interleaved with the tar output, so `docker load` gets confused, because the pipe doesn't contain clean tar data.

Is it possible to somehow maintain `executor`'s debug messages, but also send the output through a pipe to `docker load` without using a tempfile?

I'm sure there's some way to do it - I'm curious how complex it would be.

Comment: Looking at Kankio docs, it seems we can't pipe the output of tar file to stdout. Kankio only support Stdin currently - https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#using-standard-input

Comment: @Bala that link appears to be about where it gets its build context, which is unrelated to where it outputs the final image to. Using `--tarPath=/dev/stdout` already outputs the image to stdout. The only problem is that that tar data isn't the only thing on stdout. I wonder if it can be sent to `/dev/stderr` instead, and then do some bash magic to pipe stderr to `docker load`.